# Excel VBA save as PDF creates empty pages

Tags: excel, vba, export, pdf-generation

I created a button with an assigned macro in order to allow a user to easily export an excel sheet as a pdf file. Here is the code:

```
`Sub PDFActiveSheet()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strPath As String
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim strFile As String
On Error GoTo errHandler

Set ws = ActiveSheet

'enter name and select folder for file
' start in current workbook folder
strFile = Replace(Replace(ws.Name, " ", ""), ".", "_") _
            & "_" _
            & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd\_hhmm") _
            & ".pdf"
strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFile

myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
    (InitialFileName:=strFile, _
        FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
        Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

If myFile <> "False" Then
    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

    MsgBox "PDF file has been created."
End If

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub`
```

This works perfectly except for the fact that I only need it to export the first page of a worksheet. Currently, if you turn on page break view, you can see that there are 15 pages present within the active sheet, hence the generated pdf has 15 pages. *How can I edit this code in order to only have it convert the first page of the active sheet (if viewing in page break preview) to a pdf file?*

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I was able to solve the issue easily using **From** and **To** statements.